# How to use PARSE with a .net timestamp string as time in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I have .NET TimeSpan strings in my database.
I'd like to parse them as time in a SQL query.

In the following example, I'm trying to convert a timestamp string whose value is 3 days.

```
SELECT PARSE('3.00:00:00.0000000' AS time)
```

However, it is failing with the following error:

> Error converting string value '3.00:00:00.0000000' into data type time using culture ''.

Using a culture does not help at all.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) I should be able to do this.

> time  TimeSpan    DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces | DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal

I did not find any hint online at the moment.

Comment: Hi Anon. How did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is with `PARSENAME`. The below example ignores the days component of the Timespan string, returning only the time portion.

```
-- build string in HH:mm:ss.fffffff format and parse as time(7)
SELECT
    PARSE(
          PARSENAME('3.00:00:00.0000000',2) --00:00:00
        + '.'
        + PARSENAME('3.00:00:00.0000000',1) --0000000
    AS time);
```

Comment: All right, understood that the conversion goes only one way time => TimeSpan. Hours are not supported in the reverse.